# Error while creating react app in visual code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
Creating a new React app in C:\Users\midhu\OneDrive\Documents\projectone\pro1app.
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
changed 1491 packages in 37s
253 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
Missing dependencies in package.json
```

This error keeps arising. I've tried reinstalling node and other possible ways also.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

1. Go to Program Files in your C:.
2. Go to nodejs folder.
3. Find npm file, right-click on that.
4. Choose open with, and then click Visual Studio Code.
5. After you open the file on VS Code, look at line 23, can you find the "prefix -g"?
6. If its there, delete "-g" then replace it with "--location=global".
7. After that, save the file.
8. Go to file, open the file "npm cmd" in your nodejs folder.
9. Same with before, find the "-g", it might be in line 12, then replace it with "--location=global"
10. Save that, and now go to your terminal, check if you can get the node version by running "npm -v"

Good Luck!